# How to enable HTTP request logging in Azure application insights

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, httprequest, python-logging

I want to debug API calls in my Python function app, but I cannot get the logs of the HTTP requests to show up in the Azure monitor.

In the code, I added the following setup:

```
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
    
logger = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
    
sh = AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=<instrumentation key>')
logger.addHandler(sh)
logger.propagate = True
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

I expect it to give the following output:

```
send: b'GET <some_url> HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: <some_host>\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.31.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\napikey: <some_key>\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n'
header: API-Version: 1.4.1
header: strict-transport-security: max-age=157680000 ; includeSubDomains
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Content-Length: 285
header: Date: Sat, 12 Aug 2023 12:32:38 GMT
header: Keep-Alive: timeout=60
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Server: unknown
```

No logs are appearing in my function monitor, and I do suspect it has to do with the `http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1` not being registered by the log handler.

How can I enable the logging of HTTP requests in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

I tried using below Functions code to request an API and send its log traces to Application Insights and it worked successfully like below:-

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import http.client
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
    logger = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)    
    sh1 = AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=b61d789ad;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/')
    logger.addHandler(sh1)
    logger.propagate = True    
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("reqres.in")
    conn.request("GET", "/api/users/2")
    response = conn.getresponse()    
    logger.debug("Request Headers:\n%s", conn._buffer)
    logger.debug("Response:\n%s %s\n%s", response.status, response.reason, response.read())
    conn.close()

    return func.HttpResponse("HTTP request completed Rithwik")

class AzureLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, connection_string):
        super(AzureLogHandler, self).__init__()
        self.connection_string = connection_string

    def emit(self, record):        
        pass
```

**`Output:-`**

**`Local:-`**

[image]

I deployed the Function in Azure Portal. When I tested it the Logs were successfully sent to Azure application insights, Refer below:-

**`Portal Output:-`**

[image]

[image]